# MySQL Union without Union

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how many users joined each day over the last 7 days.  Something that looks like this

```
| day         | count  |
| 6/19        | 53     |
| 6/18        | 23     |
| 6/17        | 55     |
| 6/16        | 153    |
| 6/15        | 93     |
| 6/14        | 86     |
```

I would write a query like this:

```
SELECT SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) as `day`, count(*) as count FROM my_table WHERE DATE(created_at) = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
UNION ALL
SELECT SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as `day`, count(*) as count FROM my_table WHERE DATE(created_at) = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
UNION ALL
SELECT SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) as `day`, count(*) as count FROM my_table WHERE DATE(created_at) = SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

But imagine that I CANNOT use `UNION ALL` or `UNION` and it MUST be in this same table format.  How would an SQL noob do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: compare the WHERE clauses.

Comment: use `GROUP BY`.  plus more work if you want to include days with a count of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause of your query should have the condition that `created_at` is greater than or equal to the current date minus 6 days and then group by date:

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) day, COUNT(*) count 
FROM my_table 
WHERE created_at >= SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
GROUP BY day
```

Comment: I dont know why I didnt think of this.  This is so obvious. Thank you